# jqGrid - subgrid doesn't work when load once is true

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

I have a problem to use subgrid. I want to use the nice feature of loadoce(local search etc.). And I also want to use subgrid.
But it doen't work to put them together. I don't know if it's a bug or I miss some thing.

If I set loadonce:false, the subgrid works.

I tried both 3.7.1 and 3.7.2

Or should I only use one at a time?
Many thanks!

Comment: have you found an answer to this? Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in JQGrid 3.8, at least - and 4.0 (I have not tried JQGrid < 3.8).

Please be certain to have your `subGridType` set, if you want to be using `loadonce:true`, as that'll override the change from `datatype:X`(where X is what you set it to) to `datatype:local`(for your subgrid).  You probably know you'll have to set `editUrl:clientArray` for the local searches to work.

An example from a grid where I'm using the settings you want:

```
   jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid({
        colNames:['Customer','Value.','Customer ID']
        ,colModel:[
            {name:'customer_name',index:'customer_name',sortable:true},
            {name:'value',index:'value',sortable:true,align:'right',width:'100px',formatter:'number',formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:',',thousandsSeparator:'.',decimalPlaces:1,defaultValue:'0.00'}},
            {name:'customer_id',index:'customer_id',hidden:true}]
        ,sortname:'customer_id'
        ,caption:'mycap'
        ,datatype:'json'
        ,loadonce:true
        ,rowNum:100
        ,footerrow:true
        ,pager:false
        ,userDataOnFooter:true
        ,sortorder:'asc'
        ,subGrid:true
        ,sortable:true
        ,height:'auto'
        ,viewrecords:true
        ,subgridtype:'json'
        ,url:'?q=1'
        ,editurl:'?q=1&p=1'
        ,autowidth:true
        ,altRows:true
        ,shrinkToFit:true
        ,subGridUrl:'/myurl?q=1&sub=1'
        ,subGridModel:[{name:['Additional Info','Subtotal'],width:[170,60],params:['customer_id']}]
    });
```